# Make alert dialog in BaseAdapter extended class

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, baseadapter, appcompatactivity

I have a MyListAdapter Java class that it like below:

```
class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{
```

now I want to make a confirmation dialogue on each list items like below:

```
btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {




            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.setTitle("Delete");
            alert.setMessage("Are you sure?");
            alert.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // continue with delete
                new DatabaseHelper(context).deleteEmployee(employees.get(position));
                employees.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
```

But on

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

I have an error that it say:

```
builder (android.content.Context)    in Builder cannot be applied to (anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListner)
```

I don't have any problem when my class extends from AppCompatActivity

Comment: whats the activity name in which are you showing the dialog ??

Comment: can any body explain me that why down vote please???!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your trying to pass `this` as a Context, but it's pointing to your `View.OnClickListener`.

Replace:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

With:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
```